# SSIS permanently locks up

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, version 16.3.8, with SQL Server Integration Services 15.0.1300.375 the project is suddenly locking up.  When VS starts the SSIS project it runs through the "validating" messages for each piece in the design.  It's now getting stuck on one of my areas and won't stop.

Historically it would hang for a while and then eventually time out and I could fix an issue. What I'm seeing now is that 15 hours later it's still just sitting saying "validating" and Visual Studio is completely locked up.

What can I do to try and fix this?

Comment: Why is validation taking so long would be the question I try and answer. Is there something awry with a provider and/or query that it's using such that validation cannot complete? If it's a SQL Server database, I'd fire up sp_whoisactive or the like to see what that validation query is waiting on. At 15 hours, I'm guessing it's a zombie and you just need to kill devenv.exe

Comment: With laggard data sources or crazy complicated queries, a hack I use is to set the project to operate in offline mode. That will delay validation on opening the project so you can at least get to a point where you can work. No guarantee that once you try to run a package, the validation issue won't crop back up though as SSIS _must_ go through the validation process before it can run.

Comment: I've killed Visual Studio and rebooted the machine itself.  Can you tell me how to set it to offline mode without opening visual studio?  It's starting up with the file opened so I'm in a loop here ;(

Comment: Look for your .user.suo file, I think? Some file named like that records what the current state of the VS project is which includes which files were open. You can also look at editing, *very carefully*, the .dtproj file which is where you should be able to find the offline mode setting.

Comment: Thank you.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Did this issue appear in conjunction with a VS/SQL/SSIS update/upgrade? Any recent network changes?